# export csv from json file using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I do have a json file like this:
    { "skip" : 0,
      "take" : 100,
      "rows" : [
      {
        "WG": "1013",
        "Werkgever": "1013",
        "Cao": "0000"
      }
    ]}

Now I do need to convert this to csv file like this using powerhsell

```
"WG","Werkgever","Cao"
"1013","1013","0000"
```

The script is:

## Json conversion to CSV

```
Get-Content -Raw $file |
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  select @{n='WG';e={$_.WG | select -Expand WG}},
         @{n='Werkgever';e={$_.Werkgever | select -Expand Werkgever}},
         @{n='Cao';e={$_.Cao| select -Expand Cao}}|
Export-Csv $FileName1 -NoType
```

Only I do miss the value....
It comes out like:

```
"WG","Werkgever","Cao"
"","",""
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: $File = "$PSScriptRoot\Getconnector.json"
$FileName1 = "$PSScriptRoot\output.csv"

Comment: With the powershell pipeline, often the best solution with something like this to "half split the problem" and break the pipe. It's been years since I worked with PS, but a quick Google found [`Show-Object`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/26/spelunking-with-show-object/) as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
get-content "C:\temp\test.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json | % {$_.Rows} | export-csv "C:\temp\test2.txt" -NoType
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use rows property to export data

```
$content = Get-Content -Raw $file | ConvertFrom-Json
$content.rows | export-csv 'somepath' -NoTypeInformation
```